# Array doesn't update when i call it from another class

Tags: c#, arrays, class

Im trying to program the reversi game for a school assignment but i have a
 problem when im calling an array from another class.

I used this if statement to check if a move is legal. It calls the CheckLegal move method from the playermove class.

```
 if(PlayerMove.CheckLegal(Yarray,Xarray))
                {
                    //changes the turn
                    if (turn) { turn = false; } else { turn = true; }
                    if (turn) { value = 1; } else { value = -1; }

                    GameState[Yarray, Xarray] = value;

                    Board.Invalidate();
                }
```

The CheckLegal method like this.

```
public bool CheckLegal(int Yarray,int Xarray)
        {
            var Form1 = new Form1();
            bool result;
            if(Convert.ToInt32(Form1.GameState.GetValue(Yarray,Xarray)) == 0) { result = true; }
            else { result = false; }
            return result;
        }
```

The If statement, if true, changes the value of the Gamestate array at a certain point. The only problem is, is when I call for the Gamestate array in the Checklegal method, I don't get the updated value.   But if the CheckLegal method isn't in antother class I do  get the updated value.

Can anyone please explain how this works?
And how i can get the updated Gamestate value in my PlayerMove class?

Comment: `var Form1 = new Form1();` creates a new instance - it's not connected to the one you are calling it from

Comment: You are creating new instance of the `Form1`, instead you should use already existed instance of the form.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new form to check the array, this is bound to fail.

```
public bool CheckLegal(int Yarray,int Xarray)
{
    var Form1 = new Form1();
```

Its like building a new car to check if you left your wallet in the console. i mean sure you can make a new car, there is no chance your wallet will be there though

Consider making the array static, or passing the array around when you need it

---

**Further Reading**

[static (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

> Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to
>   the type itself rather than to a specific object. The static modifier
>   can be used with classes, fields, methods, properties, operators,
>   events, and constructors, but it cannot be used with indexers,
>   finalizers, or types other than classes.

[Passing arrays as arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/passing-arrays-as-arguments)

> Arrays can be passed as arguments to method parameters. Because arrays
>   are reference types, the method can change the value of the elements.

Comment: Omg thank you so much.Making it static worked. I knew it had to be something small and stupid like that. But I couldnt figure it out for hours. Really thank you.

Comment: @peerisfruit static might not be the best design, however it at least shows you how to solve the immediate problem. You might consider also declaring the array in a more fundamental place. and passing it around